# Why i'm getting error the animation clip name Up not found?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject empty i renamed it to be called: Elevator.
Under it as childs i have platform, platform1, and a button.

what i want to do is when the player ThirdPersonController is standing on platform and then click the button the elevator will move up and down none stop.

In the screenshot the Hierarchy and the script i called it Lift and the animations: Elevator and Up and Down. First i selected the Elevator then in the menu i did Window > Animation then i created animation called it Elevator but i didn't do with it anything. Then i created more two animations called them: Up and Down. When i play the Up the empty GameObject move up with the all the childes. When i play the down it's moving down.

The script Lift is attached to the Button. I also added a component Animation to the GameObject(Elevator).

This is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

This is the c# script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Lift : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool pressedButton = false;
    private bool isElevatorUp = false;

    GameObject target;

    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        pressedButton = true;
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        pressedButton = false;
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if(isElevatorUp == false)
        {
            target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            target.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Up");
            isElevatorUp = true;
        }
        else
        {
            target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            target.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Down");
            isElevatorUp = false;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(pressedButton == true)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(300, 300, 200, 20), "Press to use lift!");
        }
    }
}
```

In the Elevator Inspector i dragged to the Animation the Up animation clip.

When running the game i'm getting two messages:

1. With the sign '!' Default clip could not be found in attached animation list.
2. A warning: The AbimationClip 'Up' used by the Animation component "Elevator" must be marked as Legacy.

When i move the mouse over the button i see a small box: "Press to use lift!"
When i click the button i see error message:

> The animation state Up could not be played because it couldn't be found!
>   Please attach an animation clip with the name 'Up' or call this function only for existing animations.

Comment: Why not try marking the animation as legacy....

Comment: select the 'Up' animation asset and mark it as legacy